# Workbox is precaching URLs without revision info: /?standalone=true This is generally NOT safe

Tags: nuxt.js, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I'm building a website with Nuxt and [@nuxtjs/pwa](https://pwa.nuxtjs.org/). Recently I've started seeing this warning in the production build (deployed on Netlify).

> Workbox is precaching URLs without revision info: /?standalone=true
> This is generally NOT safe.

They did [provide a link](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-precaching#explanation_of_the_precache_list) for more information but it does little (for me) to explain how to fix the warning.

Can anyone point me in the direction of what this warning means and how I can fix it?

EDIT: So if I don't explicitly set `'start_url'` to `""` then `'/?standalone=true'` is added to the precache manifest.

Generated Precache manifest:

```
"preCaching":["/?standalone=true","/?standalone=true"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to explicitly set the `start_url` to `""` in `nuxt.config.js`

```
  pwa: {
    icon:{
      sizes: [64, 120, 144, 152, 192, 384,512], 
    },
    meta: {
      title: 'Title',
      author: 'Author',
    },
    manifest: {
      name: 'Name goes here',
      short_name: 'NGH',
      lang: 'en',
      description: "",
      background_color: '#ffffff',
      start_url: "",
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

What's generating your precache manifest?

You'll get that error message in development mode, when Workbox thinks that you've explicitly added in an entry to the precache manifest that lacks a `revision` property.

It's generally not safe because Workbox will never update the URL in question, and is only meant to be used with URLs that include inline versioning info, like `app.abcd1234.js`.

There's more context in [this issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/2259).

Comment: I'm not sure what's generating the precache manifest? I just ran npx create-nuxt-app MyApp selected PWA in the setup and that was it. Also, this warning appears in the production (deployed) build not while I'm developing

Comment: Can you share a link to a live deployment of your web app? Or paste the manifest from the generated service worker into the original question?

Comment: Sorry, the term "manifest" is overloaded. I'm asking about the precache manifest, inside of your service worker file: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-precaching#explanation_of_the_precache_list

Comment: Updated the question. Seems like the precache manifest is empty?

Comment: If your precache manifest is empty then there shouldn't be anything precached, and therefore you shouldn't end up seeing that console warning...

Comment: Apologies, I updated the question. It seems like a Nuxt issue now though not a workbox issue?

Comment: Yeah, potentially. Nuxt looks like it's adding it's own wrapper over what Workbox's doing.